# ServerResponse con Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, programación-reactiva

Acabo de terminar un curso sobre Spring Boot reactivo donde he visto como crear un api y posteriormente un cliente que utiliza el Handler con el ServerRequest y ServerResponse. Mi pregunta es la siguiente. Si yo creo un nuevo proyecto de Spring Boot para usarlo como front donde usaría Thymeleaf, ¿como puedo llamar desde un controlador a mi cliente que devuelve un ServerResponse y pasarlo a la vista de Thymeleaf?

Un saludo

Comment: Por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example]. Recuerda que debes agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Ya que tu pregunta es demasiado amplia.

Comment: especifica el mime/tipe de la respuesta que generara tu servicio para poder ayudarte